# Executing bash script on remote and "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, package

I'm trying to execute a bash script using ssh.

Say there is machine A and B. The bash script is on A and it has a command using a package installed locally in A. The package is not installed in B. I am trying to run the script from A when sshing to B. But I am constantly getting 'command not found'.

This is what I did:

```
ssh username@server 'bash -s' < local/path/to/file
```

I am wondering that is it because I don't have the package installed on B, the server? Is there any way that I can execute the script using B without having to install the package on it (my account do not have the write access to the directory)?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question that a programming professional or enthusiast would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Theoretically* you could, with lots of effort, embed the entire software in question in your script and pass that on the SSH standard input. But in the case of a properly secured server (which could even be a different platform) and a compiled program with lots of dependencies this could be anything from tricky to a multi-year project.

The trivial case of the "package" being just a single-line shell script without dependencies you could simply copy the contents of the script into your script. But the vast majority of cases are going to be orders of magnitude more difficult.

Comment: @jww I don't know why you're telling me. I voted to close it, but it's not closed yet. I just got stuck into the theoretical possibility, which I thought was a bit interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The commands passed to ssh inside the single quotes are executed on the remote host; therefore, those commands must exist on the remote host in order for them to execute there.